# Handling editText editing on small screens

Tags: android, scroll, android-edittext, android-screen-support

### Background

I have the next layout of my activity:

- vertical LinearLayout

  - TabHost with a viewPager.
  - "status bar" (an imageView/textView) .

Sometimes , in the viewPager , i have a fragment that has an EditText.

### The problem

On some screens (like the galaxy mini) , i've noticed that when you click on an editText (in order to write into it) , the softkeyboard hides everything , so you are left only with the actionBar , the tabs and the status bar .

### What I've tried

That's why i've decided to add the next flags on the manifest for this activity :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

This looked like the perfect solution - it hides the action bar , the tabs , and even the status bar when typing , leaving enough space for the editText to show (and also scrolls to it) .

However , testing it on larger screens (like the one of galaxy S3) , this has caused the softKeyboard to cover the editText in the cases where the editText was at the bottom.

I've tried to remove the adjustPan flag , which works fine for the large screen , but then on the small screen , even though it has scrolled to the editText , the status bar hides it .

I've also tried to set the [isScrollContainer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3aisScrollContainer) to true to some views , hoping that it will cause them to resize upon editing , but it didn't do anything.

### The question

What can i do in order to fix this issue , and handle all kinds of screens ?

I could check the type of the screen and use the appropriate flags programmatically (like [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setSoftInputMode%28int%29)) , but i'm not sure what should be the rules (density/resolution/screen size) , and if i really cover all types of them .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan`

with additional functionality

Make another class like this one

```
package com.example.customLayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout
{
    private OnRelativeLayoutChangeListener layoutChangeListener;

    public interface OnRelativeLayoutChangeListener 
    {
        void onLayoutPushUp();
        void onLayoutPushDown();
    }

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) 
    {
        super(context, attributeSet);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
    {
        try 
        {
            final int proposedheight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            final int actualHeight = getHeight();
            if (actualHeight > proposedheight)
            {
                // Keyboard is shown
                layoutChangeListener.onLayoutPushUp();
            }
            else if(actualHeight < proposedheight)
            {
                // Keyboard is hidden
                layoutChangeListener.onLayoutPushDown();
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    public void setLayoutChangeListener(OnRelativeLayoutChangeListener layoutChangeListener) 
    {
        this.layoutChangeListener = layoutChangeListener;
    }

    public OnRelativeLayoutChangeListener getLayoutChangeListener() 
    {
        return layoutChangeListener;
    }
}
```

now make a custome view of this class as parent in your layout xml file like this

```
<com.example.customLayout.MyRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.customLayout"

    android:id="@+id/customRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


// your original layout file

</com.example.customLayout.MyRelativeLayout>
```

try following code in your java file

myRelativeLayout=(MyRelativeLayout)findViewById(R.int.customRelativeLayout);

```
 myRelativeLayout.setLayoutChangeListener(new OnRelativeLayoutChangeListener() {

                public void onLayoutPushUp() 
                {
                    Controller_Test1.tabWidget.setVisibility(View.GONE);    
                }

                public void onLayoutPushDown() 
                {
                    Controller_Test1.tabWidget.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

Comment: So you are actually offering to detect the softKeyboard visibility , and in case it appears , i will choose what to hide , right? Any particular reason why you chose RelativeLayout ?

Comment: yes,you are going right.As android provides no way to detect that if  softkeyboard is opened or not the only solution i found while facing the same problem as you is to go with this solution and it worked well.
No any specific reason to use RelativeLayout.

Comment: i see. Nice solution . However , i've found out that since my fragment has a scrollView , using the panning flag has a problem : in case you are in the middle of the scroller , press an editText , and then try to scroll while the softKeyboard is shown , the softKeyboard will still hide the bottom views of the scrollView . Why does it happen ? Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: i dought why the adjustpan is not working in your case .Try changing adjustpan and adjustResize options in your parentmost activity containing tabs.I mean in the activity you are adding tabs to tabhost.

Comment: not sure i understand , but adding "adjustResize" would cause the problem i've reported about the galaxy s3 - it won't auto-scroll to the editText upon opening the softKeyboard.

Comment: "adjustResize" and "adjustPan" can't work simultaneously so if you have declared both of them in manifest it will apply any one of them.
So make sure that which one to use.I suggest you to test your app with them one after another.In my case i had tried both but as i was applying it on childactivity it didn't get effect.frankly speaking there is no fix solution but you have to try all the options according to situation.

Hope that info given by me enhances you by any means.
best of luck with your app.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so much! here , take both my "V" and +1 .

Comment: oh wait , sometimes , it doesn't scroll to the editText  . i've also tried to hide the action bar in addition to the status-bar , but that triggers the listener that you've created . what should i do ?

Comment: i've decided to hide the tabs too , so that there will surely be enough space . not sure why the auto-scrolling is so buggy though.